# How does Magento2 Access Control List work?

Tags: magento2, user-roles, acl, integration

I have been looking over the internet for an exposition of access control lists in Magento2 and will appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_access_control_list_rules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are main points about Magento 2 authorization system:

1. The same `acl.xml` is declaring resources used for backend actions protection and web API. It means, authorization system is now unified
2. Resulting merged `acl.xml` is used to build 2 identical ACL trees for managing permissions in the admin panel. One is on the admin user role edit page, another is on web API integration edit page
3. Permissions are checked in `\Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction::_isAllowed` when accessing admin panel pages (this method is almost always overridden in child controllers to perform check against custom resource). During web API calls processing this check is done by framework based on
   `resources` node declared in [webapi.xml](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html)
4. See any core `acl.xml` to understand the syntax, e.g. [customer module acl.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/acl.xml). Also Magento 2 has XSDs available for all configs, so if [configured properly](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-urn.html), IDE should verify and suggest correct syntax on the fly
5. To check if current user (admin or web API) has permission to access particular resource declared in `acl.xml`, just use `\Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface::isAllowed($resource)`. User context is identified automatically in this case